# Does anyone know a non-TeX equivalent for TikZ?

Tags: python, c, haskell, graphviz, tikz

Until now i have used [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to programmatically create diagrams and graphs. Recently, I found out about [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) and I started loving it. However, it would be overkill in some of my intended uses to have a dependency on TeX, LaTeX, etc. Thus, I want to see if there is a similar application as [Tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) that doesn't links with TeX concepts.

I mainly intend to use this in Haskell, Python and C. Thus, bindings for those languages will be a big plus.

Thanks

(Hopefully, I posted this in the right place. I see that there is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701902/standalone-diagrams-with-tikz) but that solution there doesn't really help me)

Comment: You know that you can generate standalone SVG or PostScript with TikZ don't you? Although you still need TeX in your workflow, your results don't need to "depend" on it. Outside of TeX-land there simply isn't anything comparable to TikZ for power or features.

Comment: I know that. But I don't want to have TeX in the deployment requirements as I intend to use the package in a program or something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you'd like the Haskell [`diagrams`](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/) library?  Also [see the gallery (click the images to view the source)](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/gallery.html).  [It's on hackage.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams)  (As far as I know there are no bindings; not sure how easy it'd be to implement them yourself.)

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was looking for. Now, I'll have to find/write bindings for C and Python as one of my projects requires them.

Comment: As always, there are problems installing this on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what features you are looking for.

Somewhat similar applications with fewer or no dependencies are:

- [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/2D%20graphs/index.html)
- [GLE](http://glx.sourceforge.net/examples/diagrams/index.html)

For Python you could try [PyX](https://pyx-project.org/gallery/graph/index.html).

Comment: GLE was good. But it still needed ghostscript, making it sound like trading one devil for another. Thanks, though.

Comment: Asymptote only seems to depend on readline and the Boehm-Demers-Weiser Garbage Collector. If you are a Mac user, there is a Homebrew formula for both Asymptote and GLE.