# Blurry text in PNG image converted from PDF via TikZ and standalone package

Tags: imagemagick, latex, imagemagick-convert, tikz, pgf

I've got a problem converting a pdflatex-generated PDF image to a PNG image using the standalone package.

The pixelated rendering of the text in the converted image (PDF->PS->PNG via gs and ImageMagick?) is awfully blurry and inferior in quality (sharpness, crispness etc.) to the screen-dumped original PDF.

I have checked out these StackExchange posts:

- [Standalone diagrams with TikZ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701902/standalone-diagrams-with-tikz)
- [TikZ to non-PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/tikz-to-non-pdf)

and been guided in the setup of my workflow by the standalone package [manual](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf). But after considerable experimental adjustment of the various conversion settings in the code below, I have been unable to improve the quality of the outputted PNG image.

A sample of the settings I have played with:

- density (increase the dpi)
- size (increase/decrease the dimensions)
- the TikZ picture width/height dimensions (no optimum found, but if too small the PNG image width does not equal that specified among the documentclass parameters)
- using the `command={}` option, I have also played with options such as -quality and - set colorspace RGB (though I didn't really know what I was doing here)

Another approach I have taken is to try to set the TikZ picture width and height dimensions (in cm) in such a way that they agree with the conversion dimensions given among the documentclass parameters (using a dpi + pixels -> cm converter).

None of this worked! So any help in converting from PDF to PNG using the standalone package that preserves the sharpness and crispness of the rendered text in the image would be hugely appreciated.

For reference the versions of the various systems/applications I'm using are:

- Windows 7
- MiKTeX 2.9
- TeXnicCenter
- gs 9.09
- ImageMagick 6.8.6 Q16 (32-bit)
- standalone package installed using MiKTeX package manager late Aug 2013

```
\documentclass[preview,convert={density=300,size=900x300,outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.style={at={(1,0)}, yshift=-0.15cm, xshift=-0.0cm,         inner sep=0pt, font=\normalsize}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
no markers, domain=-2.1*pi:2.1*pi, samples=1000,
width=30.0cm,
height=10.0cm,
axis x line*=middle,
x axis line style={densely dotted, opacity=0.75},
axis y line*=middle,
y axis line style={densely dotted, opacity=0.75},
ymin=-1.1,
ymax=1.1,
xtick={-6.28318530717959, -5.65486677646163, -5.02654824574367, -4.71238898038469,     -4.39822971502571, -3.76991118430775, -3.14159265358979, -2.51327412287183, -1.88495559215388, -1.5707963267949, -1.25663706143592, -0.628318530717959, 0, 0.628318530717959, 1.25663706143592, 1.5707963267949, 1.88495559215388, 2.51327412287183, 3.14159265358979, 3.76991118430775, 4.39822971502571, 4.71238898038469, 5.02654824574367,     5.65486677646163, 6.28318530717959},
xticklabels={$-2\pi$, $-\frac{9\pi}{5}$, $-\frac{8\pi}{5}$, $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $-\frac{7\pi}{5}$, $-\frac{6\pi}{5}$, $-\pi$, $-\frac{4\pi}{5}$, $-\frac{3\pi}{5}$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, $-\frac{2\pi}{5}$, $-\frac{\pi}{5}$, $0$, $\frac{\pi}{5}$, $\frac{2\pi}{5}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{3\pi}{5}$, $\frac{4\pi}{5}$, $\pi$, $\frac{6\pi}{5}$,     $\frac{7\pi}{5}$, $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{8\pi}{5}$, $\frac{9\pi}{5}$, $2\pi$},
ytick=\empty,
enlargelimits=false, clip=true, axis on top]
\addplot [line width=0.5,cyan!50!black] {sin(deg(5*x))*cos(deg(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem while using the same software. I think that the transparency in tikzpictures are the problem. However, I can't find an option in the standalone package to turn it off.

Comment: my experience is that imagemagick doesn't work well with ps/pdf. It uses ghostscript internally, so one should call it directly. I'd give this a try: `\documentclass[convert={ghostscript,gsdevice=png16m,
outext=.png,density=300}]{standalone}`

Comment: What makes you think that your conversion with ImageMagick and/or Ghostscript makes a detour through the PostScript file format? (you wrote: *"PDF->PS->PNG via gs and imagemagick"*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to investigate this problem I first created a PDF from your posted tikz/tex code (after copying it into a `tikz.tex` file):

```
pdflatex tikz.tex
pdflatex tikz.tex
```

The resulting PDF does contain the illustration as a ***vector*** graphic, not a *raster* image. Hence, `pdfimages -list` will NOT detect it.

Then I tested two ways to convert the resulting PDF file to a PNG:

1. Using ImageMagick's `convert` (which employs Ghostscript behind your back as a *'delegate'* to process the PDF input)
2. Using Ghostscript directly

### 1. Using `convert`with `-density 720`

I've used this command to create a PNG from the PDF:

```
convert -density 720 tikz.pdf tikz1.png
```

Here is the result:

[image: tikz1.png]

Why did I use `-density 720`? Because 720 PPI is the default resolution which Ghostscript uses when *creating* PDFs (unless you override this default setting by providing your own via `-rNxM` on the `gs` command line)...

The resulting image has a size of `374 kB` (the PDF had `49 kB`) and a `width x height` dimension of `8060 x 2390` pixels. Any pixelization (which will happen whenever you create a PNG!) is not immediately visible at that resolution.

The runtime for a loop running this command 10 times was 47 seconds.

### 2. Using Ghostscript directly

To achieve the direct PNG conversion with a Ghostscript command I used:

```
gs -o tikz-gs.png    -sDEVICE=pngalpha     \
   -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2         \
   -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 \
    tikz.pdf
```

Here is the resulting PNG:

[image: tikz-gs]

It's file size is `308 kB`, with dimensions of `8060 x 2390` pixels.

The runtime for a loop running this command 10 times was 17 seconds.

### Analysis

#### PDF input file: Sizes of components

After looking at the source code of the PDF file after uncompressing all objects, I came up with the following statistics:

```
Total size of 5 embedded Type1 fonts................................ 38615 Bytes
Total size of v`/Contents` stream (mainly used by vector drawing)... 32630 Bytes
Rest of PDF structure ("overhead", if you want).....................  5827 Bytes
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total size of PDF (after uncompressing objects)..................... 77072 Bytes
```

The fonts are `Type 1` (i.e. PostScript) fonts, according to the output of `pdffonts`. They are all embedded as subsets:

```
pdffonts tikz.pdf
 name                       type         encoding         emb sub uni object ID
 -------------------------- ------------ ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
 FXXUVH+CMSY10              Type 1       Builtin          yes yes no       7  0
 BCSIZL+CMR10               Type 1       Builtin          yes yes no       8  0
 SFJZUV+CMMI10              Type 1       Builtin          yes yes no       9  0
 WPSSUY+CMR7                Type 1       Builtin          yes yes no      10  0
 SYHYOI+CMMI7               Type 1       Builtin          yes yes no      11  0
```

Because...

- ...Fonts (unless they are *raster* fonts) are a different way to very efficiently code vector shapes for glyphs depicting text characters,
- ...Fonts + Vector drawing compose more than 90% of the total PDF size,

...there is no way in hell that lets you create a PNG raster image from the (compressed) PDF sized `49 kB` (uncompressed size was `75 kB`) that isn't larger by a few times than the original PDF file if you want to avoid directly visible "pixelization" and "blur".

Even if you use a resolution of 720 PPI (which creates a `308 kB`-sized PNG), you'll still see pixelization once you start zooming in. Such pixelization does not occur with the PDF (because all its shapes are defined as vectors).

The following three images are screenshots:

- top, from the `tikz.pdf` file at a high zoom level (~1000%),
- center, from the `tikz.png` created with 720 PPI (at a similar zoom level),
- bottom, from the `tikz72.png` created with 72 PPI (at a similar zoom level):

[image: tikz.pdf]

[image: tikz.png]

[image: tikz72.png]

The text sizes used for the annotation of the coordinate axis are only around 10 points. If you rasterize those, you'll get clearly visible pixelization at any resolution below 400 PPI, maybe even above...

---

<sub>My Ghostscript is a self-compiled `9.17 GIT PRERELEASE`. My ImageMagick is `6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for a very comprehensive answer Kurt. As I suspected, I'll need to play the 'resolution versus file size' game.